# Flex AdvancedDatagrid inline commentary functionality required

Tags: apache-flex, components, uicomponents

I'm using Flex's Advanced Datagrid for a project and need inline comments, in a similar style to Excel spreadsheet comments.

A little visual indicator should indicate if a field is associated with a comment, and on clicking on the element should open or trigger an action for displaying that particular comment.

Any suggestions on how I would go about implementing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [`ToolTipManager` class](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/managers/ToolTipManager.html) and its [usage](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/tooltips_4.html)